# What is the meaning of "x:" and of the following line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

What is the meaning of `x:` and of the following line?

```
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
```

Can somebody explain the syntax of this line?

It is from PyTorch tutorial:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html

```
# Data augmentation and normalization for training
# Just normalization for validation
data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}

data_dir = 'data/hymenoptera_data'
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=4,
                                             shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
              for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

Comment: That's a *dictionary*. If you're new to the language, start by running through a structured tutorial, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html.

Comment: A *dictionary comprehension I would emphasize - note the `for x in ['train','val']` a bit below - so `x` is one of those.

Answer (score 1):

```
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}
```

`x` comes from the `for` you have below. `for x in ['train', 'val']`, so for each value in `['train', 'val']`, you are creating a `dict` in which that `x` is the key.

This kind of construct, as **Kabanus** said, its a dictionary comprehension, a dictionary generator.

You can know more about generators in here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators

Answer (score 0):

`{x: "data/hymenoptera_data/"+x for x in ['train', 'val']}`

The results will be:

`{'train': 'data/hymenoptera_data/train', 'val': 'data/hymenoptera_data/val'}`

Basically, it takes each string from the list and forms a dictionary with two items.